# Changing date formats from MM-YYYY to DD-MM-YYYY by creating random DD

Tags: r, date, lubridate, as.date

I have a dataset that has a variable date_of_birth (MM-YYYY). I would like to change this format to DD-MM-YYYY by creating random DD for each observation.

```
df1 <- as.Date(paste0(df,"01/",MMYYYY),format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: just use random numbers between say 10 and 20, then you don't have to worry about the month lengths.

Comment: @Fattie or youcan use use `lubridate::days_in_month(date)` to get the number of days in a given month to draw from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dates <- c("02-1986", "03-1990")

add_random_day <- function(date) {
  date <- lubridate::as_date(date, format="%m-%Y")
  days_in_month <- lubridate::days_in_month(date)
  random_day <- sapply(days_in_month, sample, size = 1)
  lubridate::day(date) <- random_day
  date
}

add_random_day(dates)
```

Comment: Thank you all managed to get that working. Adapted the function and did exactly as I needed